# When verifying a RS256 JWT issued by Google, is the message significant?

Tags: rsa, google-oauth, jwt

I've gone through nearly all the steps to verify the authenticity of a JWT supposedly issued by Google. Before the last step I have the N and E parameters for RSA, and I converted the signature from base 64 to a raw string.

The library I'm using for RSA signature decoding returns a string containing a signing message upon success (and raises an error if the signature does not match). However, the message seems gibberish. Is there anything I'm supposed to do with it?

**Edit:** Here's the pseudo-code I'm using to verify.  I know that steps 1, 2, and 3 are correct. My question concerns the 4th and last step.

```
(header, payload, sig) = split_token (token)
(n, e) = find_key_parameters (header)
key = make_rsa_pub_key (n, e)
msg = rsa_pkcs1_decode (key, sig)
```

Comment: What is that message? What code do you use to verify?

Comment: I'm not sure if it contains sensitive data. I can tell you it's 51 bytes long and that it seems to contain gibberish.

Comment: You have not provided to `rsa_pkcs1_decode (key, sig)` the original message, which in case of JWT would be "base64url(header).base64url(payload)". Then `rsa_pkcs1_decode` can not verify the signature, so I guess it is extracting the signed hash with the public key. . But, Google sign tokens with RS256, therefore the hash size should be 32 bytes, not 51. Have you decoded the JWT signature from base64? could you post the documentation of `rsa_pkcs1_decode` ?